# Roslyn - Property declaration parse errors

Tags: c#, parsing, roslyn

Currently I am writing a small class member declaration sorter for C# code.

During tests I stumbled upon the following code example, comprising PropertyDeclarations, which is not parsed successfully (the example is the content of the variable `programText` of course, not the whole code below):

The code

```
private void ParseIt()
{
    string programText = @"

public class Image : ViewModifyDataBase
{

    public BoolParameter IsTransformSelfCentered { get; init; } = new(new BaseModels.BoolParameter(false));

    public ValueParameter<double> OffsetX { get; init; } = new(new BaseModels.ValueParameter<double>(0, double.MinValue, double.MaxValue));

    public ValueParameter<double> OffsetY { get; init; } = new(new BaseModels.ValueParameter<double>(0, double.MinValue, double.MaxValue));

}
    ";

    var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(programText);
    var icml = tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().Where(nd => nd.Kind() == SyntaxKind.IncompleteMember).ToList();
    // Unfortunately icml is not empty:         
    foreach(var elem in icml)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"IncompleteMember: {elem.ToFullString()}");
    }
}
```

gives the following output

```
IncompleteMember: new BaseModels.BoolParameter
IncompleteMember: (false));

IncompleteMember: new BaseModels.ValueParameter<double>
IncompleteMember: (0, 
IncompleteMember: double.
IncompleteMember: MinValue, 
IncompleteMember: double.
IncompleteMember: MaxValue));

IncompleteMember: new BaseModels.ValueParameter<double>
IncompleteMember: (0, 
IncompleteMember: double.
IncompleteMember: MinValue, 
IncompleteMember: double.
IncompleteMember: MaxValue));
```

The code snippet taken above to analyze nevertheless compiles well with normal VisualStudio (as part of a larger file) and also RoslynQuoter produces no warnings.

What can I do to accomplish a correct parse in my code too? Are there special parameter settings in ParseText() necessary?

EDIT: My roslyn (and other) versions:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AvalonEdit" Version="6.3.0.90" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Locator" Version="1.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers" Version="2.9.8" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces" Version="3.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces" Version="3.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.MSBuild" Version="3.3.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

ANOTHER EDIT: (My new settings according to your advice):

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AvalonEdit" Version="6.3.0.90" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Locator" Version="1.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers" Version="3.3.4" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces" Version="4.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces" Version="4.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.MSBuild" Version="4.7.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: You're using the post-C#9 "target-typed" `new()` operator - what version of the Roslyn Analyzers is your parser-program using? Older versions of the Roslyn/`CodeAnalysis` libraries can't parse target-typed expressions.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! I added the lines I used to draw the Roslyn modules in (copied them from a roslyn cli project standard setting in Visual Studio 2022).

Comment: You're using version `3.3.1` - that predates C# 9 - you should update to the current NuGet version (which is 4.7.0)

Comment: Thank you again: It now works flawlessly for me!

Comment: You might want to consider removing those packages and referencing _only_ `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis` - as it will automatically pull-in the right versions of the other packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer:

The OP was using older versions of the `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.*` NuGet packages that predated the introduction of the target-typed `new()` operator - introduced in C# 9.0.

As of 2023Q3, the current versions of those NuGet packages is 4.7.0, so update to those.

However, instead of having PackageReferences for individual `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.etc...` packages, you only need to reference `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis` and [it will automatically pull-in the others](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/#readme-body-tab):

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AvalonEdit" Version="6.3.0.90" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Locator" Version="1.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis" Version="4.7.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

(you may-or-may not need `PrivateAssets="all"` depending on how you're using Roslyn)